# Make UIImage fit into UIImageView inside UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm having a lot of trouble getting images to fit, with the correct aspect ratio within their UIImageView.

All images inserted initially from a plist into core data do fit with the right aspect ratio, but as images are added using the app (from the existing library of images), the images in two of three views appear larger than the view itself - so that just the top left corner of the photo is shown. In the screenshot below, the top row of the table shows an image added via the plist and the next two rows (MY RECORDS) show photos that are not confined to the view.

[image]

The cells in the above view are created in the usual way, and then configured in its own method, where it's properties are defined.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let record = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Record
    cell.textLabel!.text = record.subject
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = record.shortDetails

    if let imageArray = imagesForRecord(record)
    {
        if imageArray.count > 0
        {
            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[Int(record.featureImageIndex)]
        }
    }
}
```

But the image does not scale, nor is it clipped within the bounds of the imageView. The images that were initially loaded, like the bear, did not require contentMode or clipsToBounds to be set.

I have the same issue in a different view controller (call it VC2), but this view is defined using storyboard. I've an UIImage view that is constrained to all sides of a UIView that has fixed size constraints. The UIImage view is set to Aspect Fit, but when I set an image from the devices library it appears like the pictures above - the aspect ratio is correct, but only the top corner of the image is shown.

[image]

[image]

In yet another view, I have almost the same storyboard layout as VC2, but here it works as expected. I cannot see any difference in the constraints, properties, and the same photos are being used (from the library).

[image]

[image]

I can't see any differences, and I can't imagine how to debug from here. No doubt I am misunderstanding something quite simple about Aspect Fit or how to apply it.

Comment: Are you sure you're settings .contentMode and .clipsToBounds on the right imageView? UITableViewCell has a imageView property by default that is used to display basic cells. Also, in what function are you calling those two ?

Comment: In the storyboard, the cell's identifier is 'Cell', which is then used in the tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method to instantiate cell with tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. This cell is then passed to a configureCell method where the contentMode and clipsToBounds are added (along with text and image) before being returned by the delegate method.

Comment: use .UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill. you cant resize the image as what you are expecting now. i.e take whatsapp , they have the same problem what you are facing. so they simply stick with .ScaleAspectFill for all the images.

Comment: Show the code where you set the image and the content mode - all of it

Comment: Can you please add code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath and configureCell method.

Comment: What happens if you set the image and then call `clipsToBounds` and set the contentMode? Worth a shot since its only moving one line of code.

Comment: @NSGangster - nope.

Comment: Try printing out `imageView.frame` ? is it showing 180x140 on the certain images like your constraints have it? Wouldn't solve the problem but would get you headed in the right direction. Either rule out something happening to the imageView's frame or you know its a bug caused by something else.

Comment: That's weird, the frame is: Optional((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

Comment: Sorry - that must have been a blank page load. The frame on the Master table view is: Optional((16.0, 0.0, 132.0, 101.5))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add something like this:

```
class func imageWithImage(image: UIImage, scaledToSize newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: While this is not the answer I was hoping for - I hoped aspect fit was a built in function - you (and the other comments and answers) have shown me that despite what apple are trying to do with default layouts, it is hard to avoid specifying exactly what you need after all. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is if you use the default imageView that it doesn't contain any constraints. When you load bigger image it will display full size.

## Two solutions:

- Create a cell model, insert your imageView, and give it constraints in the storyboard.
- Check the constraints that you added to the default imageView.

For example:

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cellView.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
```

Comment: I do not think a cell model solves the problem, as per the original question, the problem exists in a storyboard model as well. I've added more details to the question to show this more clearly. I'd do it gladly if the issue in the other storyboard view was solved. I tried to check the constraints added to the default imageView as you suggest (but with newView = cell.imageView and cellView = self.View), and the images change size and act very erratically. I don't know what this tells me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true. It can help you

```
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = false
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[Int(record.featureImageIndex)]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom cell with the design that you require.
- Make the constraints in left top and bottom and set the width for the
  UIImageview.
- Add the Custom Xib with the TableView.

i hope this will Help you...